# Que veut dire « endosser » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage

Je ne sais pas tout à fait ce que le mot « endosser » veut dire. Le Trésor de la Langue française et le Wiktionnaire me montrent, à grand traits, tous les deux les sens :

1. Mettre quelque chose sur un dos
2. Prendre quelque chose sur soi
3. Écrire quelque chose au dos d’une feuille de papier de grande valeur

C’est surtout le premier sens qui me fait douter de la manière d’utiliser ce mot. J’ai lu qu’on peut endosser un harnais à quelqu’un ou à soi, mais j’ai besoin de plus de renseignements pour savoir manier ce mot adroitement.

1. Est-ce ce mot s’emploie seulement pour des vêtements ?
   Peut-on par exemple endosser un sac-à-dos, ou un autre fardeau ?
2. Est-il seulement utilisable pour les hommes, ou peut-on également dire que l’on endosse la selle à un cheval ?
3. Peut-on utiliser ce mot si on enduit quelque chose sur le « dos » d’un objet inanimé ? Ça parait étrange si je dis que « j’endosse un autocollant à mon livre », pour exprimer que je le colle sur son dos ?

Je  me rends compte que les deux dernières explications montrent déjà que le mot peut être appliqué comme je pensais. Il est cependant pensable que ce sont des emplois spéciaux,
je fais recours à ce site pour tirer ça au clair.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez, merci! Pourquoi avez-vous remplacé "ces" pour "ce"?

Comment: *Ces* ne peut être utilisé qu'en tant qu'adjectif démonstratif, ce n'est pas un pronom, il doit être suivi d'un nom. *Ces pommes*, *ces poires*, *ces emplois spéciaux*.

Comment: Pour la 3e définition, on ne l'emploie que dans certains cas. Le plus courant est **"endosser un chèque"**, c'est-à-dire signer au dos (verso) d'un chèque qui t'as été fait, avant de le déposer à la banque. En France, en tout cas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le TLFi répond à peu près à toutes tes questions.

> **A.**− Mettre (généralement un vêtement) sur son dos. Synon. *enfiler*, *mettre*. *Endosser un pardessus, une redingote, une robe de chambre*. *Endosser l'uniforme de bure de la prison* (Van der Meersch, *Invas. 14*, 1935, p. 290).

« Généralement un vêtement », donc pas nécessairement. *Endosser un sac-à-dos* ne me choquerait pas, mais en langage courant on emploierait plutôt *mettre*. Juste en-dessous, le sens transitif indirect (*endosser qqch. à qqn.*) est noté comme « rare ». Dans ce sens-là, on emploie plutôt *adosser* (cela répond aussi à ta question 3).

Pour le sens 2, il est surtout employé métaphoriquement : *endosser un rôle, une responsabilité*. C'est aussi un « fardeau », mais pas au sens physique du terme.

Comment: A noter qu'en language courant, on emploi le "mettre" pour beaucoup de choses. Je me rappelle d'un exercice en primaire qui consistait à remplacer dans des phrases courantes le "mettre" et le "faire" par des synonymes plus corrects ("mettre/dresser la table", "mettre/enfiler ses chaussures", etc...)

Answer (score 2):

> Écrire quelque chose au dos d’une feuille de papier de grande valeur
>
> Peut-on utiliser ce mot s’il si on enduit quelque chose sur le « dos » d’un objet mort ? Ça parait étrange si je dis que « j’endosse un autocollant à mon livre », pour exprimer que je le colle sur son dos ?

Non, ce troisième sens est beaucoup plus restrictif. La définition du TLFi l'indique d'ailleurs: *Porter au dos d'un titre de crédit ou d'un effet de commerce l'ordre de le payer à une tierce personne*, le papier n'est pas simplement de valeur, c'est une reconnaissance de dette sous une forme ou une autre, ce qui est écrit n'est pas n'importe quoi ni par n'importe qui, c'est le créancier qui transfère la créance à quelqu'un d'autre.

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃, _créance_ est effectivement mieux

Answer (score 0):

La signification la plus utilisée est de loin **«endosser les responsabilités»**, soit plutôt signifier sa responsabilité, seulement si, ou *en cas d'eventuels problèmes*.

Une expression au sens équivalent: **«Prendre sous son bonnet»**, est proche d'une autre expression **«Porter le chapeau»**, celle-ci signifiant *endosser* une responsabilité non-souhaité, non-désirée.

http://dictionnaire.sensagent.com/endosser%20la%20responsabilit%C3%A9/fr-fr/